# Apache Accumulo Installation

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I am trying to install Apache Accumulo 2.0 with Hadoop cluster and Zookeeper clusters already running as separate docker containers;

Now I must set the below environment variables as per installation instructions;

```
############################
# Variables that must be set
############################

## Hadoop installation
export HADOOP_HOME="${HADOOP_HOME:-/path/to/hadoop}"
## Hadoop configuration
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop}"
## Zookeeper installation
export ZOOKEEPER_HOME="${ZOOKEEPER_HOME:-/path/to/zookeeper}"
```

However these directories do not exist in local machine. Do I have to copy these directories from the individual containers of Hadoop and Zookeeper in order to make them available in local machine where I am trying to run Accumulo? Or there is some proper way to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Accumulo requires the Hadoop XML config files , as does any Hadoop client. It fines these using `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `$HADOOP_HOME/conf`

It uses `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` to get Hadoop JARs

I'm not sure what is used by having `$ZOOKEEPER_HOME`, but I guess Accumulo does not come with Zookeeper JARs either

> Accumulo will use these locations to find Hadoop and Zookeeper jars and add them to your `CLASSPATH` variable

So, yes, you need to copy them out of the container or download Hadoop libraries on the host and volume mount them into the container instead. You should already have volume mounts for Zookeeper and the NameNode & Datanodes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main purposes of the `conf/accumulo-env.sh` script in Accumulo 2.0:

1. To set up any environment, such as `CLASSPATH`, and
2. To set up any JVM arguments to pass to the `java` command.

In its most simplest form, `bin/accumulo` basically does:

```
  source conf/accumulo-env.sh
  java "${JAVA_OPTS[@]}" "$@"
```

So, any environment you export in `accumulo-env.sh`, such as `CLASSPATH`, will be set for the call to `java`. And, any options you set up in the `JAVA_OPTS` array will be passed along to `java`.

The `accumulo-env.sh` contents are expected to be customized by the user. The default contents of script try to set up the `CLASSPATH` environment for Accumulo processes by using your current installations of Hadoop and ZooKeeper. However, you must tell it where these are located on your system in order for this to work. **That is the purpose of these *'must be set'* variables.** Accumulo requires the client libraries from Hadoop and ZooKeeper, as well as the Hadoop configuration files, to be on the Accumulo `CLASSPATH`. If these are not present locally, you will need to figure out how to get them on your `CLASSPATH` for use by Accumulo and update this environment script to let Accumulo know where you put them.

If you wish to set up your `CLASSPATH` differently, you are free to do so, but you will probably want to customize a larger portion of the `accumulo-env.sh` script. This is a likely scenario for advanced users who have customized their deployment, or for vendors who have customized their vendor-provided build of Accumulo.

Comment: thanks, the question is probably around what are best practices for making these directories available on all machines of the cluster? other than download the same version distributions of hadoop and zookeeper and add to the `CLASSPATH` so that jars are available to accumulo? Any possibility to add on the `free to do so` part of answer?

Comment: The "free to do" comment refers to when you choose to diverge from the expected normal case. The expected normal case is to simply unpack the tarballs for Hadoop and ZooKeeper somewhere on your local file system, edit the config files for Hadoop, and set these variables to point to wherever you unpacked them. If you're using containers, your Accumulo container should probably already have these tarballs unpacked and an appropriate accumulo-env.sh already configured.

Comment: As for "best" practice, I don't know if this expected normal case is any better than any other practice. It depends on your situation.